# Why Visual Studio doesn't move some files in publish?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, publish

When I try to publish my project, Visual Studio doesn't move some files to target publish folder. Currently I have this problem with `.json` files. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and MVC4.

Is there any configuration about which files or mime-types should be published and moved to target folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to Visual Studio move files to target publish folder click right on the file in solution explorer and select properties then set Build Action to Content.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the **Copy to Output Directory** property of a file in Visual Studio. Click the file name, press `F4` to open the properties, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Comment: So I think this is a redundant action, isn't it? Shouldn't visual studio automatically move all files in the project?

Comment: Not necessarily, many files are for compilation only.  I.e. all your C# code gets compiled, and the output is what is copied, not the files themselves.  I think some file types get Copy set automatically, and json is probably just a file type that it VS doesn't have a default for.