# ckeditor.js not found in server but works locally

Tags: javascript, c#, ckeditor

I am working on adding ckeditor to one of the aspx pages. When I test it locally it works and the ckeditor is visible in the page. When I publish the changes to one of the windows server I am seeing the ckeditor.js file not found error.

I tried looking for .htaccess file in the ckeditor directory. The file is not there. I tried manually adding the script tag in the pages and I am seeing the same 404 errors. Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Response

```
Request URL:http://url.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

[image]

Screenshot:

Comment: Is the file completely missing?  If so, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340687/why-visual-studio-doesnt-move-some-files-in-publish) may help.

Comment: @RickRunowski I have attached a screenshot. I do not see any build action menu.

Comment: Its called Copy to output directory.  [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EteU7.png) is a link to an image showing the field.

Comment: @RickRunowski thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hollow, white icons next to the files mean they exist on the file system but are not included in the solution. IIS Express is hosting the site right out of it's project folder so you get them when debugging, but they are not included in the publish operation. You need to right click the files and include them in your project. To get CKEditor to work you don't need all the files (samples, etc.) but you will need to include files such as this (your plugins will be different so I didn't expand):

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your help and thank you for the great explanation. I am new to Visual Studio development.